# ffmpeg error in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ffmpeg, ip, visual-artifacts

I have a surveillance system with many IP cameras. I need to make a 5 sec. video clip with ffmpeg in Ubuntu 16.04. I used this command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://user:pass@ip_adress/h264 -r 9 -s 720x400 -t 0:00:5 -f mp4 -y /home/user/myvideo.mp4
```

It's fine, it made the video clip, but the whole video clip has visual artifacts.

[image: 1 sec error to video clip]

```
 built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609

 configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv

  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100

Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://log:pass@ip_adress/h264':

  Metadata:
    title           : LIVE VIEW
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.033311, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] using SAR=80/81
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] profile High, level 2.2
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=9 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/user/user.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : LIVE VIEW
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 720x400 [SAR 80:81 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 9 fps, 18432 tbn, 9 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[NULL @ 0x1c7c360] <b>RTP: missed 136 packets</b>
[h264 @ 0x523e680] <b>error while decoding MB 98 24, bytestream -5</b>
[h264 @ 0x523e680] concealing 5231 DC, 5231 AC, 5231 MV errors in I frame
frame=   13 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 
bitrate=N/A dup=0 droframe=   18 fps= 18 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 
bitrate=N/A dup=0 droframe=   23 fps= 14 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 
bitrate=N/A dup=0 droframe=   29 fps= 14 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 
bitrate=N/A dup=0 droframe=   32 fps= 12 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 
bitrate=N/A dup=0 droframe=   38 fps= 12 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 
bitrate=N/A dup=0 droframe=   44 fps= 12 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 
bitrate=N/A dup=0 droframe=   45 fps= 10 q=-1.0 Lsize=     110kB time=00:00:04.77 
bitrate= 188.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=99  

video:109kB audio:0kB 
subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.285777%
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] frame I:1     Avg QP:17.74  size: 40280
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] frame P:11    Avg QP:18.86  size:  4478
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] frame B:33    Avg QP:21.73  size:   634
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] consecutive B-frames:  2.2%  0.0%  0.0% 97.8%
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] mb I  I16..4: 10.0% 47.3% 42.8%
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  0.1%  0.1%  P16..4: 43.9% 13.7% 13.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:28.7%
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 33.1%  1.2%  0.2%  direct: 0.3%  skip:65.2%  L0:51.1% L1:46.9% BI: 2.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] 8x8 transform intra:46.3% inter:75.5%
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 84.6% 86.9% 72.6% inter: 8.8% 12.8% 1.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] i16 v,h,dc,p:  6% 26%  4% 64%
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  5% 47% 12%  4%  4%  1% 10%  3% 14%
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  9% 42%  8%  4%  5%  3% 15%  3% 12%
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 37% 51%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:18.2% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] ref P L0: 50.0%  4.3% 31.6% 11.9%  2.3%
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] ref B L0: 51.2% 33.1% 15.7%
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] ref B L1: 76.7% 23.3%
[libx264 @ 0x1dbb2c0] kb/s:176.72
```

That error 1 sec. to 5 sec. video clip. How to fix problems with this video?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The point is that if a stream of huge 10000 kbit/s that ffmpeg doesn't maintain the entering rtsp. I have given to rstp a stream of poor quality of 3000 kbit/s and artifacts have disappeared

Comment: -rtsp_transport tcp  - this key for big rtsp 10000 kbit/s stream